# Static resources versioning in servlet filter (adding an extra GET parameter)

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, httprequest, servlet-filters

im trying to implement `filter` which will somehow modify `JS` url from `/script/script1.js` to `/scripts/script1.js?version=1.3.2`

I've tried:

1. Used `response.sendRedirect("/scripts/script1.js?version=1.3.2")` and I got
   `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in browser console logs.
2. Used `RequestWrapper`, where I added in parameterMap parameter `"version"` with value `"1.3.2"`, but it needs to be added somehow into queryParameters map
   is it possible to add `queryParameters` in filter?

Or is there any solution to make this versioning in java `filter`?

PS: Yes, i know this is not the best solution, and I won't use `URLrewriteFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would think of Filters for this matter:

1.Implement a filter which encapsulates the original request into a request wrapper which adds the new parameters to the existing ones:

```
@WebFilter("/scripts/*")
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException,
        ServletException
    {
        String version=request.getParameter("version");
        if (version == null)
        {
            Map<String, String[]> myParameters=new HashMap<>(request.getParameterMap());
            request=new MyHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)request, myParameters);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ... rest of Filter boilerplate...
}
```

2.The request wrapper:

```
public class MyHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private final Map<String, String[]> parameters;

    public MyHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String[]> parameters)
    {
        super(request);
        this.parameters=parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name)
    {
        String[] values=parameters.get(name);
        return values!=null && values.length > 0
            ? values[0]
            : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
    {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

**Update**

If is needed to overwrite the `getQueryString` method, it could be done like this:

```
    @Override
    public String getQueryString()
    {
        String s;
        try
        {
            s=super.getQueryString();
            if (s == null)
            {
                s="?";
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> param : getParameterMap().entrySet())
            {
                s+="&";
                for (String value : param.getValue())
                {
                    s+=URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("Exception without treatment", e);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good aproach, but the problem is - when i add a parameter into parameter map, it just gets ignored, because there is no queryParameters defined. is there any way to make parameters from parameterMap appear in queryParameters?

Comment: @Dmitri Ilaltdinov 16 mins ago Is it ignored? How are you actually reading the parameters?

Comment: actually i was hoping that there will be no need to add anything to read those parameters, i thought that if get request will be modified that will be enough

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I ignored to overwrite the `getQueryString` method in the believing it was not necessary. Maybe it is.

Comment: @Dmitri Ilaltdinov Well, I'm not telling you to add anything more to read the HTTP parameters, but how _was you_ reading them _until now_? Are you reading them _from javascript_, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is to forward the request from the filter:

```
RequestDisptacher disp = request.getRequestDisptacher("/scripts/script1.js?version=1.3.2");
disp.forward(request,response);
```

If you do this you don't call filter.doChain(request,response).

For the forwarded request "version" will be available as a query parameter.

Comment: as i have understood this aproach - it means that there will be no more filters used affter this filter if i use getRequestDispatcher+forward?

Comment: For the inbound request, yes, assuming you don't call doChain(). Filters may be called as part of the forwarded request if they are configured for that. For example <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> included in the filter mapping definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this filter inside the JSP file that call the file.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${filter.value eq 'xxx'}">
      ... import js here
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    .... other script
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```